# remove duplicate horizontal line in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

When I switch from ggplot to ggplotly, "Virginica" seems to be duplicate with an horizontal line at  0.

```
data(iris)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

plot_iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, color = Species))+geom_density(aes(y = stat(count)))
ggplotly(plot_iris)
```

[image]

We see 2 blue lines, one of which is at 0 but with a good count. How can I remove this line ?

Comment: its an issue with how the density line is being translated for all `geom_density`s, not sure what you can do to remove it other than make a line with plotly natively. Switching to `fill` from `color` makes it a little nicer to hover: `plot_iris <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, fill = Species))+geom_density(aes(y = stat(count), alpha = .5))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by specifying `geom = 'line'` inside `stat_density`:

```r
plotly::ggplotly(
   ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
     stat_density(geom = 'line')
)
```

[image]